# Sum of two distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

How is the sum of two distribution defined? I find this concept applied throughout my book but I never found the precise definition...
Is it just $<\Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2,\phi>:=<\Lambda_1,\phi>+<\Lambda_2,\phi> $?

Comment: I am not familiar with  "sum of distributions". Could it concern the distribution of $X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables defined on the same probability space? Here I am talking about distributions in the context of probability theory, so it might be completely irrelevant what I am saying.

Comment: I think he means distribution in functional analysis as the tag implies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is probably the most natural definition for the sum of two distributions. And this is not hard to check that the $\Lambda_1+\Lambda_2$ defined in this way is a distribution.